# on press take the id and display the name of this id react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have 2 api

> first api: http://myIP/api/scategories

that  contain 'id_scategories' and 'name_scategories' and  i use this api to dispaly all 'name_scategories' in react native by fetch data

> second api : http://myIP/api/services/{id_scategories}

that contain 'service_id' , 'service_name' , 'id_scategories'

now i want to do this function :

onPress in the 'name_scategories' that displayed in react native  take the  id of this name and diplay all services of this id in another page

how can i do this?

and here is the code

```
componentDidMount(){
    return fetch('http://myIP/api/scategories')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.data,
        }, function(){

        });

      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

> ON RETURN

```
<FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
       renderItem={({item}) =>
  <TouchableOpacity  onPress= {() => navigate('service')}>
<View>
<Text>{item.name_scategories}</Text>
</View></TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: How do you define the `navigate` here ?

Comment: @PritishVaidya on render i used this     const { navigate } = this.props.navigation

Comment: You can pass it via `params` of the navigation, as mentioned [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fetch API 1, `this.state.dataSource` is an array of [id_scategories, name_scategories]. you can use this:

```
<FlatList
      data={this.state.dataSource}
      renderItem={({item}) =>
           <TouchableOpacity onPress= {() => navigate('service', {id:item.id_scategories})}>
               <Text>{item.name_scategories}</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
      }
/>
```

in `service` you can get `id_scategories` and fetch the second API like this.

```
componentDidMount(){
    let id_scategories = navigation.getParam('id', 0);
    return fetch('http://myIP/api/scategories/' + id_scategories)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          services: responseJson.data,
        }, function(){

        });

      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

Now, you can show `this.state.services` in a `Flatlist`. I did not run this code and it may have some syntax errors... 
I hope this can help you.

Comment: I'm trying to pass  id:item.id_scategories to next page but it give me this error  - cant find variable item-

Comment: if you see item.name_scategories in textbox, so check the structure of your dataSource. if the problem is about passing parameter, you can get passed parameter by `this.props.navigation.state.params.id` too.

Comment: the problem was in dataSource ,, now its work for me thank you very much @AliSn